# Error Attribute 'Computed' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to create oracle table with virtual column as below 
in liquibase
    create table MY_TABLE
    ( entry_datetime DATE not null,
      entry_date     DATE AS (TRUNC(entry_datetime)))

As per the documentation I tried to use ValueComputed attribute as below

```
<changeSet author="base_script" id="idx_31710" context="btr_rem" dbms = "oracle">
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="my_scripts" id="t11" dbms="oracle">
<createTable
          remarks= ""
          tableName= "my_table1">
<column name="entry_datetime" type="date" >
          <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
<column name="entry_date" type="DATE"  ValueComputed="TRUNC(entry_datetime)"></column>
</createTable>
</changeSet>
```

How ever when I am running it is giving error as below 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ValueComputed' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'.

I tried using computed attribute as 

but its giving error 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'Computed' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new table, not assigning the value to a column. 
This requires a `defaultValueComputed` attribute.

E.g.:
`<column name="entry_date" type="DATE" defaultValueComputed="TRUNC(entry_datetime)"></column>`